# how to create a counter that is increased at the end of the day after the total up to firebase database in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am doing a project using react js and would like to do a counter that is increased at the end of the day after the total up to firebase database and after Graph that value.

The graphics have already been solved

Comment: Sorry, it is a counter of views, I increment the state but how I know that is the end of the day for upload the total views.

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on the front end to determine when to upload data by time - if it's something you want to track then it should be sent to a server the moment that event/counter is triggered, and let your backend handle time based activities.